# Avoiding data duplication with Logical replication ( PostgreSQL 10)

Tags: database, postgresql, replication, database-replication, postgresql-10

I've configured two servers with redundancy setup using pcsd configuration.
Both machines consists of Postgres 10 and logical replication. Used below steps for logical replication setup.

- Took PG Dump on Server1 using pg_dump command.
- Restored it on Server2 with postgres 10 using pg_restore.
- Made changes in pg_hba.conf and postgres.conf files.
- Used below commands for setup of logical replication.

```
CREATE PUBLICATION my_publication FOR ALL TABLES;
CREATE SUBSCRIPTION my_subscription 
  CONNECTION 'host=Server1 port=5432 password=postgres user=postgres dbname=database1' 
  PUBLICATION my_publication WITH (copy_data = false);
```

- Restarted both servers.

After above steps I could see services are running fine on both the systems(Redundant systems). But from the logs I could see below error messages.

```
...
2020-01-08 15:14:08.551 EET >LOG:  logical replication apply worker for subscription "my_subscription" has started
2020-01-08 15:14:08.559 EET >ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_xyz_instance"
2020-01-08 15:14:08.559 EET >DETAIL:  Key (xyz_instance_id)=(103) already exists.
2020-01-08 15:14:08.560 EET >LOG:  worker process: logical replication worker for subscription 23176 (PID 7411) exited with exit code 1
....
```

As I need earlier data of Server1, I took dump and restored it on other and using copy_data as false to avoid duplication.

After every switchover of services from Server1 to Server2 or vice versa, these unique constraint violation errors are seen on Server2 (where services are inactive state)

Is there anything I'm missing here in setup of replication using PostgreSQL 10.11?

Is copy_data flag not working as I expected?

Comment: Do you have synchronous or asynchronous logical replication? How exactly does the failover process work? Please [edit] the question and add the description there. Why don't you use physical replication?

Comment: We could see sync_state as async in pg_stat_replication table.
To be exact,we are planning to move from bucardo impletation to postgresql inbuilt feature for database replication mechanism.
It would be a great help if you suggest any of these (logical/ physical) which suites more close to the bucardo implementation (which need to be dealt with multiple service switch overs) ?

Comment: How to handle duplicate key error on original primary node which is now serving as standby node. So when subscription is started on primary and secondary is publisher, then subscription fails with duplicate keys error as primary already has the data before node went down.

Answer (score 0):

With asynchronous replication, it can always happen that the standby is lagging at the point of failover and some transactions are lost. If you try to use the old primary server, which may be some transactions ahead, as new standby, the databases can be inconsistent and replication conflicts like you observe can happen.

One solution would be to use synchronous logical replication, but that reduces availability unless you have more than one standby server.

The best would be to use physical replication. Not only is it simpler and more performant, but you can also use `pg_rewind` to quickly turn an old primary server into a new standby server.

Comment: Thank you! We are configuring only 1+1. So planning for synchronous logical replication. will it make the second server database as read-only ?                                            Because while setting up the physical replication, it made my second server database as read-only.

Comment: No, the second server will be read-write (but you should not write to tables being replicated). If you use synchronous logical replication, and the standby server is down, you will not be able to perform any data modifications on the primary server.

Comment: Thank you Albe ! How can I change/configure standby to primary for replication, when primary server goes down?  When primary is down, I could see "2020-01-08 15:14:08.559 EET >ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_xyz_instance"" error messages still.

Comment: There is nothing to do to promote a logical standby except drop the subscription. If logical replication is too complicated for you, use physical replication which is simpler and much better suited for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe How to handle duplicate key error on original primary node which is now serving as standby node. So when subscription is started on primary and secondary is publisher, then subscription fails with duplicate keys error as primary already has the data before node went down